# Render an outlined red rectangle on top a 2D texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, mfc, textures, rectangles, texture2d

I have searched alot this site but couldn't exactly find what is exactly my problem. Most of the similar problems had used console and the glut library. But since I'm new to OpenGL and MFC and started it with the combination of MFC, they couldn't help me alot.

I'm customizing the class [COpenGLcontrol here in codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm) for my own purposes. [Here's the full customized class](http://www.4shared.com/rar/LGmlPcjX/OpenGLclass_customized.html) but if you're not interested in downloading it, no problem I will explain the parts that are related. This may take a while, so I hope you will be patient!

First of all I should tell you that my goal of drawing such a rectangle is that, I want to create two instances of the class in my program. 
[image]
in the smaller window the image would always be in the `zoom extent` mode but in the bigger one, the user has the ability to do different navigation tasks. So each time that for example the image is panned or zoomed in the `OnDraw` function of the bigger instance `the extent rectangle` will be computed and passed to the smaller window and drawn there to show that **where we are on the whole of such a big image**

I have followed these steps:
**Modyifying the projection matrix stack and simulating a 2D scene**

```
void COpenGLControl::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);
CWnd::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

if (0 >= cx || 0 >= cy || nType == SIZE_MINIMIZED) return;
oglWindowWidth = cx;
oglWindowHeight = cy;
// Map the OpenGL coordinates.
glViewport(0, 0, oglWindowWidth, oglWindowHeight);

// Projection view
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
// Set our current view perspective
glOrtho(-oglWindowWidth/2, oglWindowWidth/2, -oglWindowHeight/2,oglWindowHeight/2, 1, -1);
// Model view
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}
```

**Modifying the modelview matrix stack and setting camera (it seems that we are looking to the negative direction of the z-axis)**

```
void COpenGLControl::OnDraw(CDC *pDC)
{
// TODO: Camera controls
wglMakeCurrent(hdc,hrc);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0);
glTranslatef(m_fPosX, m_fPosY, 0.0f);
glScalef(m_fZoom,m_fZoom,1.0);
setViewRectangle();
if (WantToDrawRectangle)
    DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture();
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}
```

the line `setViewRectangle()` is for computing `vector<int>ViewRectangle` one of the public member datas of the class and if the user wants, the `vector<int>RectangleToDraw` other public member-data will be used to draw the rectangle. This is because we don't want in the big window to draw such a rectangle but in the smaller we do. And the smaller will use the data of the bigger.**But I haven't still implemented how to pass these data real-time between two instances of a class!**
So at time just for trying out the class, I have set the initial value of `RectangleToDraw` as follows and since the window is a `[0,0,573,543]` setted by `glOrtho`, I think the rectangle should be drawn in center, at top of the texture. But this is not the case.
anyway
**Code to apply the texture that will be called in the OnTimer**

```
void COpenGLControl::oglDrawScene(void)
{
wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);
float x0 = -ImageWidth/2; // top left corner of image
float y0 = ImageHeight/2;
float x1 = x0 + ImageWidth; // bottom right corner of image
float y1 = y0 - ImageHeight;

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
{
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);glVertex2f(x0, y1);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);glVertex2f(x0, y0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);glVertex2f(x1, y1);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);glVertex2f(x1, y0);
}
glEnd();
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}
```

**Code to compute `ViewRectangle` that will be passed to another instance of the class**

```
void COpenGLControl::setViewRectangle()
{
ViewRectangle.at(0) = m_fPosX - oglWindowWidth*m_fZoomInverse/2;
ViewRectangle.at(1) = m_fPosY - oglWindowHeight*m_fZoomInverse/2;
ViewRectangle.at(2) = m_fPosX + oglWindowWidth*m_fZoomInverse/2;
ViewRectangle.at(3) = m_fPosY + oglWindowHeight*m_fZoomInverse/2;
}
```

**Code to draw a rectangle on top of texture**

```
void COpenGLControl::DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture()
{
wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);
glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glVertex3f(RectangleToDraw.at(0),RectangleToDraw.at(1),0.5);
   glVertex3f(RectangleToDraw.at(0),RectangleToDraw.at(3),0.5);
   glVertex3f(RectangleToDraw.at(2),RectangleToDraw.at(3),0.5);
   glVertex3f(RectangleToDraw.at(2),RectangleToDraw.at(1),0.5);
glEnd();
SwapBuffers(hdc);
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}
```

even using `glVertex2f` in the above function does not make any difference and in both circumstances, I encounter:
[image]
Don't get confused. The reason that the wrong drawing is applied on both windows, is that I have set in the constructor:

```
WantToDrawRectangle = true;  
RectangleToDraw.at(0) = -100;
RectangleToDraw.at(1) = -100;
RectangleToDraw.at(2) = 100;
RectangleToDraw.at(3) = 100;
```

just for trying out how to draw a rectangle on top of a texture. Surely after writing the correct code, I will set them to the true mode. Just tell me

**How to draw a rectangle on top of a texture preferably in such an object-oriented way that I need real-time rendering?**

Comment: What is the version of OpenGL you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `edge flags` are deprecated in modern OpenGL, I would avoid using a polygon fill mode to draw the outlines. If I understand your screenshot correctly, you are getting lines on the interior edges of the two triangles used to draw your rectangle.

Instead draw a red `GL_LINE_LOOP` that uses the 4 corners of your rectangle... this is the preferred technique for portability reasons, since `GL_QUADS` are also deprecated.

```
glColor3f     (1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glBegin       (GL_LINE_LOOP);
   glVertex3f (RectangleToDraw.at (0), RectangleToDraw.at (1), -1.0f);
   glVertex3f (RectangleToDraw.at (0), RectangleToDraw.at (3), -1.0f);
   glVertex3f (RectangleToDraw.at (2), RectangleToDraw.at (3), -1.0f);
   glVertex3f (RectangleToDraw.at (2), RectangleToDraw.at (1), -1.0f);
glEnd         ();
```

Also, your screenshot appears to be suffering from attempting to texture the outline. Disable `GL_TEXTURE_2D` before you draw your lines.

Comment: took your advice but just a filled red rectangle bigger than the image on each zoom is drawn.

Comment: @sepideh: That does not make any sense, did you use `GL_LINE_LOOP`?

Comment: yeah seems that I should study glut library an do the drawings first using the glut then take my experiences in this program!

Comment: @sepideh: Oh, I think what happened is you forgot to set `glColor3f (...)` back to something sane (probably 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) and re-enable `GL_TEXTURE_2D`. Remember, OpenGL is a rather unsophisticated state machine, it has this annoying property of using "current" states and bind-then-modify. There are always `Attribute Stacks` (e.g. `glPushAttrib (...)` and `glPopAttrib (...)`) in legacy OpenGL.

Comment: thanks @Andone M.Coleman but could you explain me alittle what's the usage of `Attribute Stacks` here and what are they?  In fact How should I learn OpenGL in order to not be confused in details and ask a question for every details?

Comment: @sepideh: Well, you are learning deprecated OpenGL at the moment, these things like glBegin (...), glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D), etc. are all invalid in modern OpenGL. If you want to learn modern OpenGL http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ seems to be pretty popular. It has a higher learning curve because you cannot do anything without shaders, and this MFC OpenGL control class you have been using would eventually have to be re-written to get an OpenGL core context. But it is probably better not to learn the old API if you can avoid it.

Comment: well thank you @Andon M.Coleman Do you mean that newer versions of such classes exist?  In fact me and one of my friends are competing on doing a project and my friend has found a class that fully implements this part of the program but as much as I search the web, I just find this class to render opengl in MFC control.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36441/discussion-between-andon-m-coleman-and-sepideh)