# dynamic data exchange between two instances of the class COpenGLControl

Tags: c++, opengl, real-time, dynamic-data, multiple-instances

following my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477291/render-an-outlined-red-rectangle-on-top-a-2d-texture-in-opengl) suppose that I have two public member data in my class used as modes:

```
bool WantToSetRectangle;
bool WantToDrawRectangle;
```

and also I have two public member data which are vectors with 4 members that are used to set a rectangle and draw a rectangle.

```
vector<int>ViewRectangle;
vector<int>RectangleToDraw;
```

and this is the implementation of the class's `OnDraw` function runned after each navigation task like zooming,paning and etc.

```
void COpenGLControl::OnDraw(CDC *pDC)
{
// TODO: Camera controls
wglMakeCurrent(hdc,hrc);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0);
glTranslatef(m_fPosX, m_fPosY, 0.0f);
glScalef(m_fZoom,m_fZoom,1.0);
if (WantToSetRectangle)
    setViewRectangle();
if (WantToDrawRectangle)
    DrawRectangleOnTopOfTexture();
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
}
```

Now I create two instances of the class `COpenGLControl` in my `CDialogEx`:

```
COpenGLControl m_oglWindow1;
COpenGLControl m_oglWindow2;
```

as you see in the first picture in [my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477291/render-an-outlined-red-rectangle-on-top-a-2d-texture-in-opengl) the `m_oglWindow1` is the bigger window and `m_oglWindow2` is the smaller one. I set the modes of two windows as follows:(these modes are set `false` in the constructor)

```
m_oglWindow1.WantToSetRectangle = true;
m_oglWindow2.WantToDrawRectangle = true;
```

each time the `onDraw` function of the `m_oglWindow1` is called the `ViewRectangle` is set. these data should be dynamically passed to the `RectangleToDraw` of `m_oglWindow2` and immediately after that the `OnDraw` function of `m-oglWindow2` should be called to draw the extent rectangle on the smaller window that is always in the `Full Extent` mode.
Remember that for tasks like `Fixed Zoom in`, I can easily write this in the button click handlers of my `CDialogEx`:

```
void CMyOpenGLTestDlg::OnBnClickedButton4()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    m_oglWindow1.FixedZoomOut();
    m_oglWindow2.RectangleToDraw = m_oglWindow1.ViewRectangle;
    m_oglWindow2.OnDraw(NULL);
}
```

but in other tasks like `pan`,`zoom in to the point` and `zoom out of the point` that are implemented using `mouse-event handlers` of the class `COpenGLControl`, I need some kind of rea-time data exchange between two instances of the class:

```
void COpenGLControl::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
if (WantToPan)
{
    if (m_fLastX < 0.0f && m_fLastY < 0.0f)
    {
        m_fLastX = (float)point.x;
        m_fLastY = (float)point.y;
    }
    int diffX = (int)(point.x - m_fLastX);
    int diffY = (int)(point.y - m_fLastY);
    m_fLastX = (float)point.x;
    m_fLastY = (float)point.y;
    if (nFlags & MK_MBUTTON)
    {
        m_fPosX += (float)0.2f*m_fZoomInverse*diffX;
        m_fPosY -= (float)0.2f*m_fZoomInverse*diffY;
    }
    OnDraw(NULL);
}
CWnd::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}

void COpenGLControl::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
if (WantToUseZoomTool)
{
    if (nFlags & MK_LBUTTON)
    {
        m_fZoom = 1.05f*m_fZoom;
        m_fZoomInverse = 1/m_fZoom;
        int diffX = (int)(point.x - oglWindowWidth/2);
        int diffY = (int)(point.y - oglWindowHeight/2);
        m_fPosX -= (float)diffX;
        m_fPosY += (float)diffY;
    }
    OnDraw(NULL);
}
CWnd::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}  

void COpenGLControl::OnRButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
if (WantToUseZoomTool)
{
    if (nFlags & MK_RBUTTON)
    {
        m_fZoom = 0.95f*m_fZoom;
        m_fZoomInverse = 1/m_fZoom;
        int diffX = (int)(point.x - oglWindowWidth/2);
        int diffY = (int)(point.y - oglWindowHeight/2);
        m_fPosX -= (float)diffX;
        m_fPosY += (float)diffY;
    }
    OnDraw(NULL);
}
CWnd::OnRButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each control can notify the parent dialog that an update of the other control is needed.

```
GetParent()->PostMessage(UWM_UPDATE2, 0, 0);
```

where the user-defined messages are:

```
#define UWM_UPDATE1 (WM_APP + 1)
#define UWM_UPDATE2 (WM_APP + 2)
```

The dialog can handle these messages if you put ON_MESSAGE into its message map.

```
ON_MESSAGE(UWM_UPDATE2, OnUpdate2)

LRESULT CMyOpenGLTestDlg::OnUpdate2(WPARAM, LPARAM)
{


}
```

Comment: thanks @ScottMcP-MVP just tell me is it the right way to go? In fact I just thought about user-defined messages but since I'm new to MFC, it takes a while to implement that. This project should get ready as soon as I can, so I don't want to go the wrong way and start again from zero? So tell me if the user-defined messages is the right concept that I should study?

Comment: Yes user-defined message is the right concept for notifying a parent window. It does not take a while to implement.